# fetch api get error messages from server rather than generic messages

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, fetch-api, redux-thunk

I'm using redux thunk to fetch some data in an action

```
function handleErrors(response) {
    console.log(response)
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw Error(response.statusText);
    }
    return response;
}

export const something = (var) => dispatch => {
    fetch(`${url}/something`, {credentials: 'include'})
    .then(handleErrors)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res =>
        dispatch({
            type: SOMETHING,
            payload: res
        })
    )
    .catch(error => 
        dispatch({
            type: ERROR,
            payload: error
        })
    )
```

my express server on an error responds with 'some error'

```
return res.status(500).send({ message: 'some error' });
```

when it fetches and it's an error (500), its message is the generic "Internal Server Error".

how do I get the 'some error' in fetch?

Comment: try this github.com/github/fetch/issues/203#issuecomment-143347675

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure what’s in your `handleError`. One approach to extract the error message would be something like this

```
fetch(url)
  .then(res => {
    // Check if response has errors
    if (res.ok) {
      // No errors
      return res.json();
    } else {
       // Has errors, since res.json() returns a Promise, we
       // chain a then here to get the value and return the err value
       // as Promise rejection so that it will go to the 
       // catch handler
       return res.json().then(err => Promise.reject(err));
       // this could also be
       // return res.json().then(err => throw Error(err));
    }
  })
  .then(json => {
    // dispatch success
  })
  .catch(err => {
    // dispatch error
  });
```

Comment: You can replace your handleError function with the first `then` on this answer and remove your `.then(res) => res.json()`

Comment: can you explain to me how your code gets the actual response and not the generic one please?

Comment: Updated my answer to include some explanations. Hope that helps

Comment: @totalnoob let me know if there’s anything unclear, otherwise please accept the answer

Comment: @jpdelatorre
When I apply above, I get the error of 
"Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input".
How do I fix this