# Getting the server error message from the fetch api when status is 500 not working

Tags: json, reactjs, promise, fetch

My server is returning a 500 status error and I am trying to log what exact error the server returned.
This is my attempt. (Taken from [fetch api get error messages from server rather than generic messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49784371/fetch-api-get-error-messages-from-server-rather-than-generic-messages))

```
fetch(fetchUrl)
            .then(res => {
                // Check if response has errors
                if (res.ok) {
                    // No errors
                    return res.json();
                } else {
                    // Has errors, since res.json() returns a Promise, we
                    // chain a then here to get the value and return the err value
                    // as Promise rejection so that it will go to the 
                    // catch handler
                    return res.json().then(err => Promise.reject(err));
                    // this could also be
                    // return res.json().then(err => throw Error(err));
                }
            })
            .then(json => {
                // dispatch success
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            });
```

However, when I run the code above, I get the a error

> SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Why is this. How can I see the error what the server is returning.

(I am using React if it makes any difference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Unexpected end of JSON input` error means that something went wrong converting the body of the server's response from text to a JS object.

This means that the response was not valid JSON.

If you're using a browser, then the simplest way to do this is to look at your browser's development console's network tab and look at the raw response.

If you're not, or you'd like to do this programmatically, you can use `res.text()` instead of `res.json()`.

My guess is that your server's response body is something like:

```
My code did an oopsie
```

This is not valid JSON.

Valid JSON would be

```
"My code did an oopsie"
```

This can then be converted into a String.

Comment: I have changed it to response.text() and logged it and its showing an empty string. Does that mean the server is not telling me what the error is. How can I fix this

Comment: That's probably a different question; if the response body from a server is empty, but you expect it to be otherwise, then that's a good question to post